# PHP datetime format() incorrect date

Tags: php, datetime

I have a PHP datetime object that I have been  trying to convert into a string with DateTime::format() . But this keeps giving me a wrong date . For some reason I keep getting a date that is one day prior the day that I am running my code no matter what value I give the date.
My DateTime object -

```
object(DateTime) {
   date => '2017-03-25 00:00:00'
   timezone_type => (int) 3
   timezone => 'UTC'
}
```

I use this to format the DateTime into a  string -

```
$myDateObject->format('Y/m/d')
```

Gives me -

```
2017/03/23
```

There is absolutely no code between the line that prints the DateTime object and the line that formats the object ie there are no modifications made on the object .

If it helps the output of my server's `date -u` returns `Fri Mar 24 06:08:39 UTC 2017` . Also if I create the date string with hours and minutes using `$myDateObject->format('Y/m/d h:i')` I get `2017/03/23 12:00`

**EDIT**

The output of my `date_default_timezone_get()` is `UTC`

`date('Y-m-d')` gives `2017-03-24` ie today's date

Comment: How do you create `$myDateObject` ? Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: does echo `date('Y-m-d');`also give the wrong date? And what timezone is your php setup to use? Try `date_default_timezone_get`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [default time zone set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) in PHP
you may wanna try setting default time zone example:  date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');